# Android : "Screen overlay detected" when scanning for MetaWear tag

Tags: android, system-alert-window

I got this nice new MetaWear C device, and I've been building an Android app that collects accelerometer data, no problem. Except all the sudden, when I start the scan via the BleScannerFragment, I get, following the location permission request, the message "Screen overlay detected", with an option to "Open Settings". This option opens the screen overlay permission settings, but I cannot grant permission to the application, because it does not list it in its Manifest.

When I re-installed the MetaWear app, I get the same issue. I could add the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission to the Manifest in the SDK, but I'd rather not go there. Adding the permission to the Manifest in my own project did not solve it.

Has anyone run into this problem before and have any idea how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: What's stranger, if I attempt to change my app's permissions through my phone's settings, I get the same message and I cannot change any of the permissions. Re-installing did not change that

Comment: Although I somehow doubt other people will run into this issue, the only solution I found, strangely enough was uninstalling, changing the application ID and reinstalling it.